# Improper Double Integrals: Sketching and switching the order

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Problem 1** Sketch the domain of integration and express the integral in the opposite order.
>   $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$

The question is exactly what is quoted above. I looked through the textbook we were given in class, and looked at other threads on here but I couldn't find anything dealing with an improper double integral for an arbitrary function. Any information on how to go about switching the order of integration and/or what a sketch of such an integral would look like is highly appreciated.

Comment: this picture is quite far fromoptimal

Answer (score 0):

A sketch of the domain is the unbounded area between the lines
$$y=x$$
and
$$y=0$$
for $x\geq 0$.

To switch the order of integration, you have

\begin{gather}
0\leq y \leq \infty \\
y \leq x \leq \infty
\end{gather}

which covers the same domain as the original integral. This gives 
$$\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f(x,y) \, dx\,dy$$
which would be less useful, as you have two improper integrals now.

To switch to polar coordinates, $dA$ becomes $r\,d\theta\,dr$ and
\begin{gather}
x=r\cos(\theta)\\
y=r\sin(\theta)
\end{gather}

Your limits become
\begin{gather}
0\leq r \leq \infty \\
0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{gather}

giving

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))r \, d\theta \,dr$$

Comment: I think the integral must be switched to Polar coordinates and evaluated that way, but I don't know if the improper integral in the original problem should become r or theta...

Comment: You didn't state that you wanted to switch to polar coordinates, but doing that will still yield an improper integral. I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: I dont have to switch it i just thought it might make it easier. Are you saying theres not anything to be done with this or what? Im sort of confused

Comment: You can't evaluate the integral without knowing what the function is. The question asked to sketch the domain and change the order the variables are integrated in, which I have done.